# Комбинация клавиш в Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, hotkeys

Форма закрывается при нажатии любой кнопки кроме Ctrl. При нажатии Ctrl открывается вторая форма.

```
if (GetKeyState(ord(VK_CONTROL)) < 0) then 
begin
 form2.show;
end
else
begin
 Application.Terminate;
end;
```

Я бы хотел чтоб вторая форма открывалась по комбинации клавиш. Например, Ctrl + Tab:

```
if (GetKeyState(ord(VK_CONTROL)) < 0) and (GetKeyState(VK_TAB) < 0) then 
begin
 form2.show;
end
else
begin
 Application.Terminate;
end;
```

Но этот способ не срабатывает, тк первая форма закрывается сразу же при нажатии клавиши и вторая форма просто не успевает открыться. Надо сделать так, чтоб при нажатии клавиши форма не закрывалась сразу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так все работает

```
if (GetKeyState(ord(VK_CONTROL)) < 0) then
begin
  if (GetKeyState(ord(VK_TAB)) < 0) then
  begin
    form2.show;
    showcursor(true);
  end;
end
else
  Application.Terminate;
```